# Adobe Acrobat Pro DC - Any way to copy all text in a specific column?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, acrobat-pro-dc

I have a rather large PDF that has about 17,000 pages. It's all the same format of being text data in multiple columns. Is there a way to capture the text just in a specific column? I know I can alt-select to just copy text in a column, but that seems to be limited at a per page basis. I need to collect all the data in an entire column (all ~17,000 pages worth). The other alternative is to copy all the text into a spreadsheet, but doing so loses the tab information and everything ends up being jumbled together with space separation instead of tab separation.

Comment: This might be possible with an Acrobat script. Are you familiar with Javascript? https://evermap.com/javascript.asp

Comment: https://developer.adobe.com/document-services/apis/pdf-extract/ may also be an option